# "Unable to stop the stream: Device or resource busy" when using Opencv with flask. Works well when flask isn't imported

Tags: python, opencv, flask

I've been trying to stream video from a webcam to a flask website. But whenever I call cv2.VideoCapture(id) I get the following error (once for each of my 8 cameras):

```
VIDEOIO ERROR: V4L2: Pixel format of incoming image is unsupported by OpenCV. Unable to stop the stream: Device or resource busy
```

But whenever I request the video feed outside the context of flask everything works as it should.

Here is my code:

**web_server.py**

```
import cameras
from flask import Flask, request, render_template, Response
from flask import jsonify
import sensors
import gps
import system_monitor
import cv2


app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/_livedata', methods= ['GET'])
def livedata():
    accel_value, distance_object, heading, gyroscope_object, speed = sensors.get_sensor_reading()
    current_coordinates = gps.get_gps_coordinates()
    cpu_usage, ram_uage, gpu_usage, vram_usage = system_monitor.get_system_info()
    return jsonify(speed=round(speed, 2),
                    acceleration = accel_value,
                    cpu=cpu_usage,
                    ram=ram_uage,
                    gpu=gpu_usage,
                    vram=vram_usage,
                    distance1=round(distance_object[0]/100,2),
                    distance2=round(distance_object[1]/100,2),
                    distance3=round(distance_object[2]/100,2),
                    distance4=round(distance_object[3]/100,2),
                    distance5=round(distance_object[4]/100,2),
                    distance6=round(distance_object[5]/100,2),
                    distance7=round(distance_object[6]/100,2),
                    distance8=round(distance_object[7]/100,2))

def gen(id):
    """Video streaming generator function."""
    while True:
        frame = cameras.get_video_feed(id)
        cv2.imwrite('t.jpg', frame)
        print(frame)
        yield (b'--frame\r\n'
               b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + open('t.jpg', 'rb').read() + b'\r\n')

@app.route('/video_feed/<id>')
def video_feed(id):
    id = int(id)
    """Video streaming route. Put this in the src attribute of an img tag."""
    return Response(gen(id),
                    mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')


def start(host, port ,debug):
    app.run(host, port, debug)
```

**cameras.py**

```
import cv2
import numpy as np


cap = cv2.VideoCapture(3)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH,1280);
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT,720);

cap1 = cv2.VideoCapture(2)
cap1.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH,1280);
cap1.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT,720);

cap2 = cv2.VideoCapture(6)
cap2.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH,1280);
cap2.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT,720);

cap3 = cv2.VideoCapture(7)
cap3.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH,1280);
cap3.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT,720);

cap4 = cv2.VideoCapture(5)
cap4.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH,1280);
cap4.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT,720);

cap5 = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cap5.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH,1280);
cap5.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT,720);

cap6 = cv2.VideoCapture(1)
cap6.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH,1280);
cap6.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT,720);

cap7 = cv2.VideoCapture(4)
cap7.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH,1280);
cap7.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT,720);

print("Cameras Started!")



def get_all_video_feeds():
    ret, img = cap.read()
    ret1, img1 = cap1.read()
    ret2, img2 = cap2.read()
    ret3, img3 = cap3.read()
    ret4, img4 = cap4.read()
    ret5, img5 = cap5.read()
    ret6, img6 = cap6.read()
    ret7, img7 = cap7.read()

    #output = np.concatenate((img[0:720 , 0:1240], img1[0:720 , 0:1240], img2[0:720 , 0:1240], img3[0:720 , 0:1240], img4[0:720 , 0:1240], img5[0:720 , 0:1240], img6[0:720 , 0:1240], img7[0:720 , 0:1240]), axis=1)

    #output = cv2.resize(output,(6832,480))
    #cv2.imshow('image', output)
    return (img, img1, img2, img3, img4, img5, img6, img7)

def get_video_feed(id):
    if id == 0:
        ret, img = cap.read()
        return img
    elif id == 1:
        ret1, img1 = cap1.read()
        return img1
    elif id == 2:
        ret2, img2 = cap2.read()
        return img2
    elif id == 3:
        ret3, img3 = cap3.read()
        return img3
    elif id == 4:
        ret4, img4 = cap4.read()
        return img4
    elif id == 5:
        ret5, img5 = cap5.read()
        return img5
    elif id == 6:
        ret6, img6 = cap6.read()
        return img6
    elif id == 7:
        ret7, img7 = cap7.read()
        return img7
```

**[Note]**

- I'm calling the .start() method of web_server.py from another file
  (currently this file only calls this method).
- I am not using those cameras in any other script.
- Running cameras.py without web_server.py gives the wanted results
  when calling the functions in it.
- Operating System: Ubuntu 16.04

Thanks in advance